# Start capacitor on shaded pole to increase starting torque- how to size

Tags: capacitor, motor

Can I add a capacitor to a shaded pole motor to increase starting capacity? How do I size it? I have a single pole squirrel cage motor running a conveyor toaster that is dying while trying to start. Just want to give it a bump 120v 60hz i=1:320.7

Comment: I've never seen a shaded pole motor with a separate start winding. So, probably, no... Can you reduce friction or load instead?

Comment: shaded-pole motors produce only a small starting torque. is this the original equipment recommended motor type for the application? I would consider moving to a different type of motor

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that.  You need a different kind of motor.